# Map numpy array and sum values on positions in another array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, optimization, sum

I have 2 numpy arrays:

```
distances = np.array([
    [0, 6, 7, 4, 2],
    [6, 0, 6, 3, 8],
    [7, 6, 0, 9, 3],
    [4, 3, 9, 0, 4],
    [2, 8, 3, 4, 0]
])

path = np.array([3, 1, 2, 0])
```

In `path`, there are locations, which I want to visit. Each location is index to `distances`. So in example above, I visit location `3`, then `1`, then `2`, then `0` and then back to `3`. For this I would like to calculate sum of distances `3, 1`, `1, 2`, `2, 0` and `0, 3` (path is closed circle).

You can get distance between `3` and `1` from `distances[3, 1]` (= 3), between `1` and `2` from `distances[1, 2]` (= 6), etc. Distance in example above should be `20`.

I created this function:

```
import time
import numpy as np

distances = np.array([
    [0, 6, 7, 4, 2],
    [6, 0, 6, 3, 8],
    [7, 6, 0, 9, 3],
    [4, 3, 9, 0, 4],
    [2, 8, 3, 4, 0]
])

path = np.array([3, 1, 2, 0])

def get_distance(path):
    distance = 0

    for i in range(len(path) - 1):
        distance += distances[path[i], path[i + 1]]

    distance += distances[path[-1], path[0]]

    return distance

start = time.time()

for i in range(100000):
    get_distance(path)

end = time.time()
print(end - start) # 0.206
```

It's working, but I need run this function many times (e. g. milion times) with long path (e. g. 50 locations), so I would like to optimize it. Is there any way?

Comment: @Divakar why not turn it into an answer?

Comment: @iliar Seemed pretty simple, but not a dupe it seems. Posted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can simply slice the indexing array and index into the `distances` array to get those specific distances, then sum those for the final output. As with the original code, we will sum the last pair separately. Hence, it would be -

```
distances[path[:-1], path[1:]].sum() + distances[path[-1], path[0]]
```